# Issues Powershell to refresh Excel ODBC via Macro

Tags: excel, powershell, odbc, vba

I am using the following Powershell script to open an Excel file, run a Macro (which performs an ODBC data refresh), save the file and then close it.

```
$ErrorActionPreference="SilentlyContinue"
Stop-Transcript | out-null
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"
Start-Transcript -path "\\xxx\report automation\eurcauto.txt" -append

$objectExcel = new-object -c excel.application
$objectExcel.displayAlerts = $false # don't prompt the user

$Classeur = $objectExcel.workbooks.open("\\yyy\Reports\Operate Metrics\Automation\EURC_Weekly_Metrics.xlsm", $null, $true)
$objectExcel.run("AutoUpdate")
Start-Sleep -s 1200
$Classeur.saveas("\\yyy\Operate Metrics\EURC Reports\EURC_Weekly_Metrics_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).xlsm")
$Classeur.close($false)
$objectExcel.quit()
spps -n excel
Remove-Item "\\yyy\Operate Metrics\Automation\EURC_Weekly_Metrics.xlsm"
Start-Sleep -s 60
Copy-Item "\\yyy\Operate Metrics\EURC Reports\EURC_Weekly_Metrics_$((Get-Date).ToString('dd-MM-yyyy')).xlsm" "\yyy\Operate Metrics\Automation\EURC_Weekly_Metrics.xlsm"


Stop-Transcript
```

My issue is that the data is not getting refreshed.

I thought that might be because the file was saving and closing before the refresh has completed. it takes ~15mins, so I added the 'Start-Sleep -s 1200'(20 mins) line - But for some reason the sleep command is not being honoured.

I am not sure if the sleep line is required, or if there is another reason the data is not refreshing. Also I am not sure why the Sleep command is not being honoured.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you try `$objectExcel.Run("EURC_Weekly_Metrics.xlsm!AutoUpdate")`?

Comment: I tried that without the sleep command. Doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Did you try simple macro like only msgbox to show some message and it can run or not. Excel has security to block macro to run when start excel, Try to set macro security to low(run macro on startup without alert).